# fgetc prints wrong characters to console

Tags: c, file, file-io, char, printf

My program is supposed to print the text contained in a text file, which is saved in the same directory as both the source code and the executable, and then print the number of lines.
However, the output is some random characters.
I am using ubuntu.

Follow up question: which one has to be in the same directory as the file (if I don't specify the absolute path), the executable or the source code? 
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  char c;
  int i = 0;

  FILE *fp = fopen("newfile","r"); 
  if(!fp) {
    printf("Error opening\n");
    return -1;
  }

  printf("Text of newfile: \n");
  while(fgetc(fp)!=EOF){
    c = fgetc(fp);
    printf("%c",c);

    if(c == '\n')
      ++i;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  fp = NULL;
  printf("\nThere are %d lines in the file\n",i+1);

  return 0;
}
```

The file cointains the text:

```
this is my file
this is line 2
```

output:

```
Text of newfile: 
hsi yfl
hsi ie2�
There are 2 lines in the file
```

Comment: You're discarding half the characters in the file, and will print the first EOF half the time.

Comment: Not exactly random characters, more 1/2 characters of input file. Plus past the end char...

Comment: You call fgetc twice in your loop, but only print one result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters you are using  `fgetc` two times in the loop

```
  while(fgetc(fp)!=EOF){
        ^^^^^^^^^ 
    c = fgetc(fp);
        ^^^^^^^^^
    //...
```

Secondly the variable `c` must be declared as having the type `int`.

The loop can look the following way

```
int c;

//...

while ( ( c = fgetc( fp ) ) != EOF )
{
    putchar( c );
    if ( c == '\n' ) ++i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I'm unsure why you would declare c as an int, it works as a char too since the return from fgetc is casted automatically into a char I believe.
Also it says there are 3 lines, although there are only two.

Comment: @thep1rate In general the type char can behave as signed char or unsigned char. So in the case when the type char behaves as unsigned char when you will never get that c == EOF.:) Because there will be compared two values (c = ) 255 and (EOF = ) -1.

Comment: @thep1rate As for the second part of your question it might be that there is an "empty" line in your file.